# PHP POST & GET on the Same Page

Tags: php, mysql

Im running into Trouble here, im self learning php and trying to sort out POST and GET on the same vieworder.php

for POST i have vieworder.php 
and for the GET i am using vieworder.php?order_id=550c92216efdb

my Post is working and Sending data to the Database but When i click on vieworder.php?order_id=550c92216efdb its telling giving me 
 Undefined index: for all fields..

Comment: Are you trying to make the page do different things based on whether the request is GET or POST?  Or are you trying to mix GET and POST in the same request? (Hint: Don't do the second one)

Comment: vulnerable to both SQL Injection and XSS/javascript injection from hackers here...

Comment: I am trying to make the page do different things based on wheter the request is a GET Or POST

Comment: I feel like the following: `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ ... } else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') { ... }` could really help in your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your undefined index error is because when you send a `GET` request `$_REQUEST['pizzaSize']`, and your other `$_REQUEST` keys aren't set.

Use `isset()` to determine if they are set or not as your other code does.

Your SQL error is because `order_id` is a string and needs to be encased in quotes.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM order WHERE order_id = "' . htmlspecialchars($_GET['order_id']) . '"';
```

Also you should consider reading up on SQL injection. I could delete your whole database with a dodgy `pizzaSize` (amoung others) variable.

Comment: [code]$query = 'SELECT * FROM order WHERE order_id = "' . htmlspecialchars($_GET['order_id']) . '"';[/code]   Is still giving Syntax error

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
if (isset($_POST['your_post_variable_name'])){}
```

for catch your post and

```
if (isset($_GET['your_get_variable_name'])){}
```

for get. In this way you can handle each one separately.

Comment: Thanks that has Separated them but when i click on the Link, its showing a Blank Page.. am i using the Query rightly  ??

Comment: I think nothing wrong with your query. I think it is better to use this if statements and go ahead step by step. echo your variables, try step by step logging to find out where is your problem.